# Referring to asp:literal by class instead of ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have several literal controls on my aspx page and they all have the same value. This means that in my code behind, I have to write this 10 times:

```
TheLiteral1.Text = "SameValue";
TheLiteral2.Text = "SameValue";
```

Is there a way to reference all the literals on the page, or a way to reach them via a class name like in CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a list of the literal controls on your page by getting the Controls collection and filtering them by type, like so:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

List<Literal> literals = new List<Literal>();
foreach (Literal literal in this.Controls.OfType<Literal>()) 
{
    literals.Add(literal);
}
```

Then, you can loop through the list and set their values.

```
foreach (Literal literal in literals) 
{
    literal.Text = "MyText";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend on NWard's answer, you could also write a custom method which will search a parent control for all controls of a specified type.

```
public static void FindControlsByTypeRecursive(Control root, Type type, ref List<Control> list)
{
    if (root.Controls.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in root.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.GetType() == type) //if this control is the same type as the one specified
                list.Add(ctrl); //add the control into the list
            if (ctrl.HasControls()) //if this control has any children
                FindControlsByTypeRecursive(ctrl, type, ref list); //search children
        }
    }
}
```

With this highly reusable method, you can either search the entire page (pass `this` as the parameter in the page's code-behind), or a specific container like a data-bound control :)

Comment: Yes! This is especially useful as an extension method on the Control collections, so you can call List<[type]> controlList = this.Controls.FindByTypeRecursive(Type type) and have it return your calling code's controls and its child control sets as a new list.

Answer (score 1):

to build on NWard's answer, you could filter through using Linq's Where:

```
foreach (var literal in Controls.OfType<Literal>().Where(x => x.CssClass=="MyCSSClass") 
{
    literals.Add(literal);
}
```